# How to set command line environment variable in PHP shell_exec

Tags: php, command-line

The script I am trying to run via shell_exec in PHP requires an environmental variable to be set, which afaik is done via:

```
export VARIABLE=value
```

However, to run the script I am forced to do:

```
<?PHP
$sOutput = shell_exec("export VARIABLE=value && my_command_goeth_hereth");
```

It seams kinda pointless to have to export the variable every time I run any commands.

Is this the only way to do it, or am I missing a much simpler way?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Since environment variables are inherited, setting them inside your script will set them for the commands it launches too. You just have to use [`putenv`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.putenv.php).

```
putenv("VARIABLE=value");
```

Answer (score 6):

Won't just:

```
<?PHP
shell_exec('SOMEVAR=SOMEVAL /some/program');
```

do the trick?

If you're running multiple shell scripts, then [putenv](http://php.net/putenv) is your friend, as zneak pointed out.

**EDIT** with an exmaple:

env.php:

```
<?PHP
echo $_ENV['FOO'];
echo "\n";
```

runenv.php:

```
<?PHP
echo shell_exec('FOO=bar php env.php');
```

then try 
`$ php runenv.php`

Comment: Why is this any different from what I am doing above?
i.e. `export VARIABLE=value && command`

Comment: it's nearly the same thing.  But you don't need to export if you just want the environment to apply to a single script/program.  More than one and you're probably better off with putenv()