# Issue running unoconv from php script with shell_exec

Tags: php, shell, pdf, command, uno

I am unable to use unoconv to convert a .doc to PDF from php using exec.  Here is what I am trying:

```
$output = exec("unoconv /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/=".$fileData['name']);
error_log(print_r($output, TRUE));
```

This command, when run in the console works perfectly, but when run through php, it gives the following in the error logs:

```
python: /opt/bitnami/common/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by python)
python: /opt/bitnami/common/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by python)
Aborted
[Thu Mar 28 20:13:58.312843 2013] [:error] [pid 1481] [client ***]
```

I don't think the first two lines are relevant, and I'm not sure how to get more information on why it aborted.  I also have tried running it using this wrapper stored in /usr/local/bin/unoconv.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -z "$1" ]; then
    echo "Must pass file";
    exit 10;
fi

/usr/bin/unoconv -f pdf $1.rtf
```

But that gives the error

```
python: /opt/bitnami/common/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by python)
python: /opt/bitnami/common/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by python)
/usr/local/bin/unoconv.sh: line 8:  2886 Aborted                 /usr/bin/unoconv $1
[Thu Mar 28 20:17:05.331830 2013] [:error] [pid 1188] [client ***]
```

Any ideas on what else to try?  Thanks for your help

Comment: distribution of linux/unix?

Comment: Sorry, it's Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS

Comment: result of this: `pkg-config --libs openssl`?

Comment: No package 'openssl' found

Comment: run: `apt-get install openssl` and than: `pkg-config --libs openssl`, and check your script.

Comment: If I remember correctly you don't have an environment when you do shell_exec or similar. That means that all your paths and other settings are not available. Also consider that you do the shell exec as the webserver's user so it may be that this user cannot access certain components in the system.

Comment: Running `apt-get install openssl` overwrote the existing package, but it still says no package 'openssl' found.

Comment: Do I need to change the pkg-config search path?

Comment: @jamie0726 Is there anyway around this?  It seems like using the wrapper would work.

Comment: your version of `openssl`?

Comment: @DavisG. check out this post how to set env variables in combination with shell_exec http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571582/how-to-set-command-line-enviroment-variable-in-php-shell-exec

Comment: It is 1.0.1 and it is found in the directory /opt/bitnami/common/lib/pkgconfig

Comment: @jamie0726 Sorry, I'm not sure how I would use this as a solution

Comment: you have to find out what env variables unoconv is missing (I never used it, so I can't help you on this). But here's a posting which looks interesting how to continue debugging: http://askubuntu.com/questions/96512/php-shell-exec-in-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

I've done it with exec();

```
$path_exe = "\"C:\Program Files (x86)\LibreOffice 4\program\python.exe\" c:\unoconv\unoconv -f png ";
exec('"C:\Program Files (x86)\LibreOffice 4\program\python.exe" c:\unoconv\unoconv -f pdf 'c:\'.$filename, $array_buffer, $code_error);
```

You should specify the path to the python.exe, and the path to **unoconv**